# SELECT DISTINCT with COUNT

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I want to count the number of patients that are not currently admitted (`CurrentClinicalInfo = 'False'`). However, there are multiple `ClinicalInfo`s per patient. Therefore I need to select distinctively.

I have tried this code below but it comes with too many column leading to errors further on.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS TableLength
    FROM            PatientDemographics AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             PatientClinicalinformation AS pc ON p.PatientID = pc.PatientID
    WHERE        (pc.PatientID IS NULL) AND (p.FirstName LIKE '%' + + '%') OR
                             (pc.PatientID IS NULL) AND (p.Surname LIKE '%' + + '%') OR
                             (p.FirstName LIKE '%' + + '%') AND (pc.CurrentClinicalInfo = 'False') OR
                             (p.Surname LIKE '%' + + '%
    ') AND (pc.CurrentClinicalInfo = 'False')
```

Comment: **count(Distinct CurrentClinicalInfo)**

Comment: My suggestion would be to run this without the aggregate first to make sure you have the correct records, then apply the `count()`. Then if you want to count distinct rows, you will use `count(distinct ClinicalInfos)`.

Comment: @will Can you provide sample output that you desire.

Comment: The mix between ORs and ANDs made my mind blown. I think you miss a lot of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want distinct Patients, correct?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.PatientID) AS TableLength
FROM PatientDemographics AS p
LEFT JOIN PatientClinicalinformation AS pc ON p.PatientID = pc.PatientID
WHERE pc.PatientID IS NULL AND p.FirstName LIKE '%' + @input + '%'
      OR
      pc.PatientID IS NULL AND p.Surname LIKE '%' + @input + '%'
      OR
      p.FirstName LIKE '%' + @input + '%' AND pc.CurrentClinicalInfo = 'False'
      OR
      p.Surname LIKE '%' + @input + '%' AND pc.CurrentClinicalInfo = 'False'
```

Comment: Works great, how can i do the same with a SELECT Distinct TOP([number]) * ... with the same stuff from FROM`?